# Groupby nunique versus unique with categorical data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe and perform a `groupby` with `unique` after filtering via a mask. My grouper series is categorical. I am using Python 3.6.0 / Pandas 0.19.2.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'sku': ['A0', 'A0', 'A2', 'A2', 'A3', 'A3'],
                    'ID': ['10', 'T1', 'T1', 'T2', '10', '20']})

df1['sku'] = df1['sku'].astype('category')
res = df1[df1['ID'].str[0] == 'T'].groupby('sku')['ID'].unique()

sku
A0        [T1]
A2    [T1, T2]
A3          []
Name: ID, dtype: object
```

This works as expected. Now with `nunique` I would expect `[1, 2, 0]`.

But instead I see `[1, 1, 0]`:

```
res = df1[df1['ID'].str[0] == 'T'].groupby('sku')['ID'].nunique()

sku
A0    1
A2    1
A3    0
Name: ID, dtype: int64
```

If I omit conversion to categorical, the result is as expected:

```
res = df1[df1['ID'].str[0] == 'T'].groupby('sku')['ID'].nunique()

sku
A0    1
A2    2
Name: ID, dtype: int64
```

Why is the result different depending on whether the grouper is categorical?

Comment: What is the output of `res = df1[df1['ID'].str[0] == 'T'].groupby('sku')['ID'].apply(lambda x: x.nunique())`?

Comment: @user3483203, That works with or without conversion to categoricals. But `lambda` not ideal and still a bit confused :S

Comment: If that fixes it, then it seems like the remnant of a bug left over from 0.17, which involved `nunique` on categorical data when not all categories were present.  Seems to have been fixed from 0.21 onwards

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your problem, however I'm running pandas 0.23.1, so maybe it was fixed in more recent versions?

Comment: I'm surprised you get results at all actually, I get a `ValueError`

Comment: `In [8]: pd.__version__
Out[8]: '0.19.2'`.  It's [this](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11635) bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11635) from version ~0.17, fixed in ~0.21+.